# Какое поле базы данных mysql-server mysql-client 5.7 хранит пароль и какой функцией шифрует?

Tags: mysql

Установил **mysql-server mysql-client** командой: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. Таблица user не имеет поля password, вместо него есть поля: `authentication_string`, `password_expired`, `password_last_changed`, `password_lifetime`. Поле `password_last_changed` хранит время последнего изменения пароля. А где хранится сам пароль? И какой хэш функцией он хешируется,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранится в `authentication_string`

Хешируется в зависимости от параметра `default_authentication_plugin`:

- **mysql_native_password** - встроенная функция mysql (по умолчанию)
- **sha256_password** - SHA256

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin